# From a list of dictionaries in python Django how to filter/find and highest valued prize per user per day

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

***I want to find out per day per user what is the highest prize he has won***

```
my_list = [{'id': 1, 'user_id': 4, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 9), 'prize': '45.00'},
{'id': 2, 'user_id': 5, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5), 'prize': '85.00'},
{'id': 3, 'user_id': 5, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5), 'prize': '35.00'},
{'id': 4, 'user_id': 4, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 9), 'prize': '95.00'},
{'id': 5, 'user_id': 3, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 9), 'prize': '10.00'},
{'id': 6, 'user_id': 6, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5), 'prize': '15.00'}]
```

the result should be as below

```
result = [{'id': 2, 'user_id': 5, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5), 'prize': '85.00'},
{'id': 4, 'user_id': 4, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 9), 'prize': '95.00'},
{'id': 5, 'user_id': 3, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 9), 'prize': '10.00'},
{'id': 6, 'user_id': 6, 'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5), 'prize': '15.00'}]
```

**In above Example user_id=4 have 2 prizes on date(2022, 9, 5) i.e $45 and $95.
Among these 2 we have to pick the highest valued record $95**

Comment: Why is this question tagged "django"? If this is the result of a query using the Django ORM please include the model and queryset used

Comment: Why does the expected output not have `user_id=1`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max
Model.objects.all().values('user_id','date').annotate(max_prize=Max('prize'))
```